# Query to remove duplicate calculated values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a client running SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1, and I can't seem to write a query that has distinct calculated values. I could change the schema to store the value being calculated, but I was curious if there was a way to do this from within a query without modifying schema (for scenarios where client schema modification is not possible)?

City Table:

```
+-------+----------+--------------------------+----------+
|  id   |   name   |       displayName        | countyID |
+-------+----------+--------------------------+----------+
| ...   | ...      | ...                      | ...      |
| 833   | Portland | Portland, Ashley, AR     | 3323     |
| 21388 | Portland | Portland, Clackamas, OR  | 5439     |
| 21655 | Portland | Portland, Multnomah, OR  | 5462     |
| 21726 | Portland | Portland, Washington, OR | 5470     |
+-------+----------+--------------------------+----------+
```

County Table

```
+------+------------+----------------+---------+
|  id  |    name    |  displayName   | stateID |
+------+------------+----------------+---------+
| ...  | ...        | ...            | ...     |
| 5439 | Clackamas  | Clackamas, OR  | 38      |
| 5462 | Multnomah  | Multnomah, OR  | 38      |
| 5470 | Washington | Washington, OR | 38      |
+------+------------+----------------+---------+
```

State Table

```
+-----+-------+---------------+
| id  | State | StateFullName |
+-----+-------+---------------+
| ... | ...   | ...           |
| 38  | OR    | Oregon        |
+-----+-------+---------------+
```

Query:

```
   select top 100 City.id as cityID
    ,City.name + ', ' + [State].[State] as label
    ,[State].[State] as stateAbbrev
    ,[State].StateFullName as stateName
from [City]
left join [Country] on (City.countyID = Country.id)
left join [State] on (Country.stateID = [State].id)
where City.name + ', ' + [State].[State] like 'Portland, OR'
```

Results:

```
+--------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| cityID |    label     | stateAbbrev | stateName |
+--------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
|  21388 | Portland, OR | OR          | Oregon    |
|  21655 | Portland, OR | OR          | Oregon    |
|  21726 | Portland, OR | OR          | Oregon    |
+--------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

The desired query would return only one row for distinct values of the calculated column "label". As I mentioned earlier, I'm curious if there's a solution that doesn't involve schema modification since that may not always be possible.

Comment: `The desired query would return only one row for distinct values of the calculated column "label"` how do you define which one to keep ? The row with 21388 , 21655 or 21726  ?

Comment: Also, a `TOP(N)` without `ORDER BY` will not guarantee any order !

Comment: I had an `ORDER BY`, but it used columns I removed from the simplified query, so I removed it. Good tip though, thanks!

Comment: @Kin In my example, it doesn't matter which one to keep since the "county" relation became an un-needed complication in this query, so I don't care precisely which city/county it refers to as long as it has the correct city name. The question is mostly about how to work around bad schema if I run into this situation in the future.

Comment: you will need to use `ROW_NUMBER()`. I have a [**sqlfiddle here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/52d59/4). Let me know if that is the expected output that you need.

Comment: Why do you need to return CityID at all?

Comment: @Kin I edited your fiddle to add back in the missing schema data (the state/county for 'Portland, AR') and it worked!! I will accept that if posted as an answer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't. This query was originally for a type-ahead API that was initially designed to be searched as "City, County, State", but was also used in a second type-ahead that needed "City, State" search. The correct answer was to modify the schema to store this data as well, but I was curious how it would be solved in a query if the client would not let us modify their schema. CityID is not needed by the query, and was included here to show where each result came from.

Comment: If you can't modify the schema, and you don't need CityID in the output list, then removing CityID (and the arbitrary, non-deterministic TOP) and adding DISTINCT (or a GROUP BY) should also be able to solve the problem. If you add a GROUP BY you could even include something like MIN(CityID) or MAX(CityID) if you really wanted to carry along one of those meaningless values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment as answer ([**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/52d59/5)):

```
;with cte (cityID, label, rowNum, stateAbbrev, stateName)
as (
    SELECT 
    TOP 100 City.id AS cityID,
    City.name + ', ' + [State].[State]  as label,
    row_number() over (partition by cast(City.name + ', ' + [State].[State] as varchar(max)) order by City.id desc) AS rowNum, -- if you want the highest cityID then use "desc" else remove the "desc"
    [State].[State] AS stateAbbrev,
    [State].StateFullName AS stateName
  FROM [City]
  LEFT JOIN [Country] ON(City.countyID = Country.id)
  LEFT JOIN [State] ON(Country.stateID = [State].id)
  WHERE City.name + ', ' + [State].[State] LIKE 'Por%'
  order by City.id)  -- I have put in order by 
select cityID, label, stateAbbrev, stateName
        from cte
        where rowNum = 1
```

The above will result :

[image] ([click here to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STXre.png))

*Note: As Aaron commented, you should remove CityID if not required in output list.*